# Import/Export Plugin - will not install on IP3.9

Tags: plugins, impresspages

Maybe I am making a fundamental error, but I assume you have to install the Import / Export plugin on IP3.9 to make the zip file before you import it to the new ip4.1 site ?

The plugin will not install in IP3.9 there is an error "plugin.ini doesn't exist"

The Import / Export plugin is not in the IP3.x format
*ip_plugins/group_name/plugin_name/files*
so I do not see how it can be installed.

If I try exporting data from IP4.1 I get the following error message

Error: 
**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method Ip\Page::getType() in **/var/www/ip41/Plugin/ImportExport/ManagerExport.php** on line **207**

I am probably doing something stupid, but I cannot see what

Alan

Answer (score 0):

For v3.x version you must download a 3.x branch of the plugin - https://github.com/impresspages-plugins/ImportExport/tree/3.x

For the error in v4.1 open an issue on GitHub - https://github.com/impresspages-plugins/ImportExport/issues

I hope it does make sense now.

Comment: Many thanks.  I have tried it quickly on my localhost "test bed" site. Here are some of the results. From the IP3.9 export there are following messages:Warning: skipping non-exportable widget \Modules\data\ImportExport\widgetsExport\IpColumns     Warning: skipping non-exportable widget \Modules\data\ImportExport\widgetsExport\IpForm   so it seems there are problems  with the IP forms and column widgets.   On IP4.1 side there was a problem importing images /var/www/ip41/file/secure/tmp/archive_2014_06_15_0931/archive/file/euFlag200.png   I will keep trying to see if I can solve the situation.

Comment: Hi again. I have just unpacked the zip file made by the IP3.9 export plugin.  There is nothing in the file directory, so it appears the problem is with the IP3.x plugin.     Alan

Comment: Hi yet again, I have just opened 2 issues on GitHub for the 2 problems I have described above.  It is the first time I have used GitHub, so I hope I did it correctly.